# Need help raising Code Coverage

Tags: trigger, unit-test, code-coverage, failing-tests

I've been working on a trigger to auto-populate some information that goes into our company's Tasks. I have come up with the following trigger/test class but can only seem to get Coverage around 45%. When I check the Coverage it says that the lines associated with the "taskMap" (lines 12-22) are those not being covered. Can someone show me exactly what I'm missing?

Trigger:

```
trigger Task_Autopopulate on Task (before insert, before update) {
    Set<String> whoIds = new Set<String>();
    for (Task t : Trigger.new) {
        whoIds.add(t.WhoId);
    }
    List<Contact> cons = [SELECT Id, Direct__c, Email_2__c, Email_3__c, Fax,  
        Fax_2__c, MobilePhone, Phone_2__c, Phone_3__c, Website__c, 
        MailingCity, MailingState, MailingCountry FROM Contact WHERE Id =: 
        whoIds];
Map<String, Task> taskMap = new Map<String, Task>();
for (Task t : Trigger.new) {
    taskMap.put(t.WhoId, t);
}
for (Contact c : cons) {
    if (taskMap.containsKey(c.Id)) {
        taskMap.get(c.Id).Direct__c = c.Direct__c;
        taskMap.get(c.Id).Fax__c= c.Fax;
        taskMap.get(c.Id).Fax_2__c= c.Fax_2__c;
        taskMap.get(c.Id).Mobile__c= c.MobilePhone;
        taskMap.get(c.Id).Phone_2__c= c.Phone_2__c;
        taskMap.get(c.Id).Phone_3__c= c.Phone_3__c;
        taskMap.get(c.Id).Website__c= c.Website__c;
        taskMap.get(c.Id).Contact_City__c = c.MailingCity;
        taskMap.get(c.Id).Contact_State_Province__c = c.MailingState;
        taskMap.get(c.Id).Contact_Country__c = c.MailingCountry;
        }
    }
    update cons;
}
```

Test Class:

```
@isTest
private class Task_Autopopulate_Test {
    static testMethod void Task_Autopopulate_TestMethod() {
        Set<String> whoIds = new Set<String>();
        List<Contact> cons = [SELECT Id, Direct__c, Email_2__c, 
            Email_3__c, Fax, Fax_2__c, MobilePhone, Phone_2__c, 
            Phone_3__c, Website__c, MailingCity, MailingState, 
            MailingCountry 
            FROM Contact 
            WHERE Id =: whoIds];
        Map<String, Task> taskMap = new Map<String, Task>();
        Contact con = new Contact();
        con.FirstName = 'Test';
        con.LastName = 'Contact';
        con.Direct__c = '0000000000';
        con.Email_2__c = 'email2@email.com';
        con.Email_3__c = 'email3@email.com';
        con.Fax = '0123456789';
        con.Fax_2__c = '1234567890';
        con.MobilePhone = '1111111111';
        con.Phone_2__c = '2222222222';
        con.Phone_3__c = '3333333333';
        con.Website__c = 'email.com';
        con.MailingCity = 'Test';
        con.MailingState = 'State';
        con.MailingCountry = 'USA';
        insert con;

        Task t = new Task();

        test.startTest();
        insert t;
        update t;
        test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

To say I'm an amateur, particularly with test classes, would be an understatement so please keep that in mind. Thanks!

Comment: I can't see where you task is associated to the test Contact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nearly there - try something like:-

```
    @isTest
    private class Task_Autopopulate_Test {
        static testMethod void Task_Autopopulate_TestMethod() {
            Contact con = new Contact();
            con.FirstName = 'Test';
            con.LastName = 'Contact';
            con.Direct__c = '0000000000';
            con.Email_2__c = 'email2@email.com';
            con.Email_3__c = 'email3@email.com';
            con.Fax = '0123456789';
            con.Fax_2__c = '1234567890';
            con.MobilePhone = '1111111111';
            con.Phone_2__c = '2222222222';
            con.Phone_3__c = '3333333333';
            con.Website__c = 'email.com';
            con.MailingCity = 'Test';
            con.MailingState = 'State';
            con.MailingCountry = 'USA';
            insert con;

            Task t = new Task();
t.subject = 'A subject';
//insert other required fields here...
    t.whoId = con.id;

            test.startTest();
            insert t;
            update t;
            test.stopTest();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The whole trigger is based around the task's WhoId, but you are not setting the WhoId in your test.

```
Test.startTest();
Task t = new Task();
t.WhoId = con.Id;
insert t;
Test.stopTest();
```

I would also create another test for testing update

```
Task t = new Task();
insert t;

Test.startTest();
t.WhoId = con.Id;
update t;
Test.stopTest();
```

Also you should also be using some `System.assertEquals` afterwards to make sure your code is actually performing the desired changes in your trigger. That's the whole point of writing unit tests.